# Confidence interval for binomial success parameter approximated by normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

Given is a group of 82 people, 7 of those are at risk for some disorder. The overall goal is to model the proportion p of people with the disorder - and it is clear that this can be modeled by a Binomial distribution.

The task, however, goes on to say the following:

**"With the central limit theorem (CLT) it follows that $\hat{p}$ follows approximately N(p, p$\frac{1}{n}$(1-p)). Plot the normal approximation for different n and p, compare the binomial distribution to the normal approximation for different n and p. Calculate the 95%-confidence interval (CI) for the approximate proportion".**

I am very confused because it is not clear to me what $\hat{p}$ is - I assume it is the estimated distribution (and not just the success parameter). But would this not be N(np, np(1-p))? And if this is
the estimated distribution, how can I construct a CI for it?

Comment: $\hat{p}$ is a point estimate of $p$ to use in your binomial distribution

Comment: So then, while the MLE of p is simply x/n, I would use here N(x/n, x/n * n * (1-p)) to get the normal approximation of p? Or what do I substitute for p in N(p, p*1/n (1-p))?

Comment: Your bolded hint seems to be pointing to the second of your suggestions.  There are other approaches to [binomial proportion confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

Comment: I don't really understand, because they say "Compare the binomial distribution to the normal approximation for different n and p." If the formula above is just a point estimate, how can we compare it to the binomial distribution?